# Transposing Specific Data in CSV

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
Month     Day   Year  Tmax
   4       1    1912    56
   4       2    1912    56
   4       3    1912    74
   4       4    1912    82
   4       5    1912    79
   4       1    1913    73
   4       2    1913    60
   4       3    1913    67
   4       4    1913    81
   4       5    1913    77
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
Year  Month   1     2     3      4     5 
 1912   4     56     56    74     82    79
 1913   4     73     60    67     81    77
```

So each `Day` is now a column header and `Tmax` are displayed as columns instead of rows.  I have played around with unstacking and transposing but can't seem to quite get it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, can also do it this way:  `df.set_index(['Year','Month','Day']).unstack()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `pd.pivot_table()` with `index` as `['Year', 'Month']` and `columns` as `'Day'` on `'Tmax'` values.

```
In [10]: pd.pivot_table(df, values='Tmax',
                        index=['Year', 'Month'],
                        columns='Day')
Out[10]:
Day          1   2   3   4   5
Year Month
1912 4      56  56  74  82  79
1913 4      73  60  67  81  77
```